# Adding a new 4GB stick gives Memory Management BSOD on Windows, works fine on Ubuntu, stress tester doesn't detect the 4GB one on Windows

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, memory, memtest, stress-test

Let me enumerate the issues I have come across.

1- My mobo is Asus Z97-C. I screwed up one of the pins when I was installing the CPU for the first time so I had to have it fixed. But it works fine now.

2- I have two Kingston RAM sticks, one 8GB, one 4GB. I have the 8GB one in the first slot, and no matter which slot I stick the second stick into, it works on Ubuntu with no issue, but gives Memory Management on Windows 10 x64 Professional.

3- Windows Memory Diagnostic Tool detects an error on the first try. But seeing as it's a Microsoft product doesn't really delve much into it.

4- Memtest64 stress test doesn't detect the 4GB stick. I have monitored Task Manager when it runs the test, it never goes past 7.3 GB. It doesn't detect any errors.

5- Ubuntu has absolutely no issue. It detects the second stick and uses it.

What could the issue be?

Comment: Sounds like the pin;  What you describe absolutely could be caused by that damage

Comment: @Ramhound but the pin is fixed. The CPU has no issue. Plus why does it only dysfunction on Windows?

Comment: You indicated that MemTest64 doesn’t detect the memory.  That indicates a memory channel problem caused by a bent pin